# Second monitor remains black after installing nvidia 270.18 driver

Tags: xorg, nvidia, xinerama

I've installed the latest nvidia 270.18 driver from the [~ubuntu-x-swat](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat) PPA. Since the driver has been installed my second monitor remains black. In `nvidia-settings` the second monitor is detected correctly, but I couldn't get the second monitor to display anything. I can move any windows or the mouse cursor to the second monitor, but I can't see anything on the second monitor.
Ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm that all the connections to the monitor have been checked?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards